# how to sync outlook calendar events with mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, outlook

I´m looking for a starting point on how to sync outlook 2013 calendar events with a mongodb. NodeJS is used as a platform. I would prefer c#, but if any other like vb.net is better suited for the task it´s ok.

Comment: downvoting from some self proclaimed ... without a comment is stupid - get a life

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop an Outlook add-in. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.

Also you may find the [Outlook Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386094.aspx) section in MSDN helpful.